# How to read the all texts in multiple .txt files

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a problem in my program (multiple choice exam) where I don't know how code to read all text in multiple files.

the examinees will first register their (name, age, gender, contact number) then they will proceed to the exam.

After the exam the results will be displayed (correct answers, wrong ans, total items).

After that all of this will be saved in a .txt file using `StreamWriter`
Note: my streamwriter has an auto naming (like windows)

E.g.:

```
xReg.txt, xReg(1).txt, xReg(2), xReg(n).txt
```

This is what i did and it just write all of the contents of all the .txt files but i would like to have an option to view 1 file in my menu.

```
public class FilesL
{
    public static void alltxt()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Examinees", "*.txt", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var a = File.ReadAllText(file);
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        Ad.Admin();
    }
}
```

this is my admin login to menu btw

```
public class Ad
{
    private static string User = "";
    private static string Password = "";
    private static int instance = 3;
    public static string fileName = @"C:\\Examinees\xReg.txt";

    private static void V()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\tAdministrator");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nMenu\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t1) View Examinees' Results\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t2) Restart Program\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t3) View Test\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t4) Terminate Program\n\n");
        Console.Write("Select: ");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                FilesL.alltxt();
                break;
            case 2:
                Home.H();
                break;
            case 3:
                Questions.exam();
                break;
            case 4:
                Clear.terminate();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice, please try again!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                V();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void Admin()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou need to log-in to confirm that you are the ADMINISTRATOR.");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗");
        Console.WriteLine("\t║\t  !   Login Confirmation   !      ║");
        Console.WriteLine("\t╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝");

        Console.Write("\n\tEnter Your Username: ");
        User = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("\tEnter Your Password: ");
        Password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (User == "Admin" && Password == "AAAA")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            V();
        }

        else
        {
            instance--;
            Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, you entered a wrong input! \nPress 
            Enter to Continue.\n\nAttempts Left: {0}", instance);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            if (instance == 0)
            {
                Clear.terminate();
            }
        }
    }
    while (User != "Admin" || Password != "AAAA");
    Console.Clear();
}}
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  If you haven't tried anything then it's too soon to be posting a question here.  You need to do some research first.  It's not hard to find out how to read a file, so you should be able to at least attempt that part.  It's not hard to find out how to get all files in a folder either.  Put the two together and that's your question answered.  You try first and, if you fail, come back and show us what you did and tell us what happened.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, as written, your question is off-topic as "too broad": there are many ways to solve such a problem, and no "right" answer. Also, as written, you haven't shown any work; you've just posted the project's requirements (it appears to be a classroom/homework project), and asked the community to solve it for you. And this isn't how Stack Overflow works. Also, please note that there is no urgency here; you cannot ask for help "asap". If you really need something immediately, you'll need to look elsewhere (perhaps asking your instructor for assistance).

Comment: You can try with loop and read separately then concatenate all

Comment: sir @DavidMakogon i'm sorry for the late response. it is indeed an homework project. i also forgot to post the progress of my project (my bad), but now i posted it in the answers below.

Comment: sir @jmcilhinney sorry for the late update. i posted my progress on the answers below. i focused on working on that yesterday and i forgot to post my progress (mybad).

Comment: @RhonStratos - unfortunately you posted your code in the wrong place; you should have edited your question. It doesn't help posting your code as an answer, as it isn't an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test\", "*.txt");
    List<string> data = new List<string>();

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file))
        {
             string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();   
             data.Add(fileContent);
        }
    }
```

- Output
  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLIyE.png

Comment: You are missing `;` in `data.add(fileContent)` line. Please edit.

Comment: @SH7 now you can able to see output of all text file content retrieve in list type of string

Comment: ok very good, not clear why you are tagging me. I didn't mark you the down vote.

Answer (score -1):

Please find other solution

```
    using System.IO;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\SampleStackoverflow\", "*.txt");
        foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
        {
            var fileStream = new FileStream(currentFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Do the action of Storing the file content
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```